# Backbone View Won't Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm having a little trouble figuring out why my Backbone view isn't showing up in the browser. I'm running through some Backbone tutorials, and I'm just trying to change the code a little bit to make a basic RPG to practice on, but I'm stumped as it looks like it should work. Here's the code:

```
//MODEL
var Monster = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        health: '',
        defense: '',
        attack: '',
        damage: ''
    }
});

var goblin = new Monster({name: 'Gobby', health: 10, defense: 10,
    attack: 5, damage: 4});

//VIEW

var MonsterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'monster',
    template: _.template('<table>' +
        '<th><%= name %></th>' +
        '<tr><td>Health</td> <td><%= health %></td>' +
        '<td>Defense</td><td><%= defense %></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Attack</td><td><%= attack %></td>' +
        '<td>Damage</td><td><%= damage %></td><tr>' +
        '</table>'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

var monsterView = new MonsterView({model: goblin});
monsterView.render();
```

To go with this, I just have a basic html doc with an empty div with the id of 'monster'. It appears to be right, but here's what the Chrome console tells me:

monsterView -> el: div#monster, model: child (has all of the right attributes)

If I do monsterView.render() in the console, it prints undefined in the console. However, if I enter the follow into the console or include it in my app.js file, the view looks like it should:

```
$('div').append(monsterView.template(monsterView.model.toJSON()));
```

Thanks for your help. It will probably be an easy one for a non-noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an existing div with id monster:

```
var MonsterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#monster',
    template: _.template('<table>' +
        '<th><%= name %></th>' +
        '<tr><td>Health</td> <td><%= health %></td>' +
        '<td>Defense</td><td><%= defense %></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Attack</td><td><%= attack %></td>' +
        '<td>Damage</td><td><%= damage %></td><tr>' +
        '</table>'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it into `$(document).ready(...);`
And you'll need to declare element as `el: '#monster'`, `tagName` `id` combo won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that you need to point your view to render somewhere on your page.

Try something like:

```
var monsterView = new MonsterView({
    model: goblin,
    el: $('.my-container')
}.render());
```

where `my-container` is an element that already exists on your page.